# Cache RDD and add executer

Tags: apache-spark

Scenario:

- start a cluster with 1 node
- start application with spark.Executer.instances=10
- create an RDD repartition to 100 parts and cache it.
- add 9 more nodes to the cluster

You will see all 10 executers has been accepted to the application but actual working node is only the first one.

Does anybody know if this is the way it was intended to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the way it is intended to work.

- Partitions of an RDD are cached on a specific node.
- DAG, and as result inputs, outputs and number won't change, unless everything is recomputed. Which brings us to previous point.

Answer (score 0):

So when creating a RDD checkpoint which needs caching, in this case you have to rdd.unpersist before using.